# Sample Size for Adaptive Lasso

Tags: regression, sample-size, lasso, goodness-of-fit, mse

Be gentle, I'm learning here. I have a fairly simple adaptive lasso regression that I'm trying to test for a minimum sample size. I used cross-validated mean squared error as the "score" of model accuracy. Where I am stuck is how to analyze each group of samples to determine at what point the CV-MSE stops being significantly different from the last smaller size. I believe the tactic is good, or maybe not; please tell me. But I am just stuck on how to decide which sample size to select.

The figure is a box plot with jitter, each dot representing one test. Cross-validated MSE is on the Y-axis, and the simulation's sample size is on the X-axis.

Just for clarity, this is just a one-time regression model using alasso with predictor and response variables. I'm not training a model for testing. It "looks" like the CV-MSE levels out around 375-400 cases. What I'm asking here is, is there a better way than eye-balling the plot to determine the optimal sample size I need to collect to run the test? Is it as simple as doing a series of t-tests or repeated measures ANOVAs between each sample size to see when there is no longer a significant difference between MSEs? I'm looking for some technique that will stand up to the scrutiny of peer review. Any thoughts would be appreciated!

[CV-MSE Plot for visual representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sf7dF.png)

Comment: I wouldn't focus on 'significantly different' here, that's more likely than not a function of the number of sample draws you're making. I'm almost certain the line will be straight (i.e. keep going down) in the log scale. The question is what precision you want.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what "precision" is, in these terms, can you clarify? Bottom line for me with this test is determining the minimum sample size I need to collect to have sufficient power and/or good-fit for the model. I don't know if CV-MSE is the right statistic to use, or maybe R^2? But, ideally, I'd like to be able to write "the sample size was 400 for this model because in our model simulations, our fit statistics/variance did not significantly improve past this number of cases...." something like that. As you can tell, I'm not sure of the question to ask, just of what my end goal is.

Comment: I might not be using the correct terminology myself, but I would express this in terms of 'we can make a prediction to within X% of its true value with certainty Y' (or the ratio of the error to the outcome value or so). It then comes down to how precise you want to be. Most likely you'll find this is multiplicative and need for example 10x sample size to reduce error by 10-fold at any point. Going from 10% to 1% error might be worth it, but that may no longer hold for going from an error of $10^{-5}$ to $10^{-6}$. This is essentially the flattening you're seeing on a non-log axis.

Comment: To restate a bit: my guess is that at no point the relative error will stop going down proportional to the sample size, so that never becomes 'non-significant'. You should rather figure out in absolute terms when the error becomes negligible. The former is similar to how you can still get very low *P*-values for differences that are irrelevant in practice.